# Shell script to store each line of a file to separate files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I am trying to get the line contents of file (./answer/answerOnly.txt) to separate files.

Given -> answerOnly.txt:

```
Ans1
Ans2
Ans3
Ans4
```

expected output ->
files to be created

```
~/Desktop/miniPro$ ls distributedAnswers/
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
```

and 1.txt contains:

```
~/Desktop/miniPro$ cat distributedAnswers/1.txt
Ans1
```

I have tried ->

```
for (( i=0;i<count;i++ ))
do
 echo -n `awk 'NR==$i' answer/answerOnly.txt  &> ./distributedAnswers/$i.txt`
done
```

output : Empty files are getting created

observation : "awk 'NR==$i'" will only accept numbers. Need a way in which 'NR== ?' accepts variable value.

Thanks and your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider coding such a script in [Python](http://python.org/), or [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/), or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or code a simple C program for it?

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `split`?

For example:

```
split -d -l 1 answersOnly.txt  answer_ --additional-suffix=.txt --suffix-length=1 --numeric-suffixes=1
```

How it works:

- `-d` use numeric values
- `-l` split by number of lines, here `1`
- `answerOnly` is your input file
- `answer` is your output file
- `--additional-suffix=.txt` appends `answer` with `.txt`
- `--suffix-length` add a suffix of length `N`
- `--numeric-suffixes` same as -d, but allow setting the start value

Or... use `bash`.

Here's how:

```sh
readarray -t LINES < "$1"
COUNT=${#LINES[@]}
for I in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
    INDEX=$(( (I * 12 - 1) / COUNT + 1 ))
    echo "${LINES[I]}" >> "$((I + 1)).txt"
done
```

Where `"$1"` is your source file.

Answer (score 3):

i'm assuming that in the filename `${i}.txt`, `i` is the line number

so would this help?

```
#set a line counter variable i outside the block
i=0

# start a while loop that reads the file line-by-line
while read line; do

    #increment the counter by 1 for each line read
    i=$(($i+1)) 
    # write to file
    echo "$line" > ${i}.txt

done < answerOnly.txt
# passing the file as input using < (input redirection)
# you could also use `cat answersOnly | while ...etc` but this is cleaner
```